# Replace occurrences within capture groups using Regex

Tags: arrays, ruby, regex, string

tl;dr: How do I replace only specific characters (i.e. line breaks) in a regex match in Ruby?

I have an array of strings. Each element of the array has between 2 and 4 words (= any sequence of characters) divided by spaces in a specific sequence.

I also have a large string in which I want to check for instances of those word sequences which are broken by \n instead of space. For example, I want to match an element of the array:

```
arr[0] = "aaa bbbb ccccc"
```

to a string that looks like this:

```
zzzzzzzzz aaa\n
bbbb ccccc yyyyyyyyy
```

And make it look like this:

```
zzzzzzzzz aaa bbbb ccccc yyyyyyyyy
```

The thing is, I can think of at least two ways of doing it, but they seem very cumbersome. What I would do is:

1. replace each space in the array with [ \n]
2. generate a regex with Regexp.union comprising all elements of the array
3. use the regex to match instances of my arr elements in the string
4. generate a .gsub! for each string so that it does not replace the entire match, but only elements of the match (or use multiple capture groups)

I suspect, however, that this is a rather silly way to do it. Is there a way to do it in Ruby that is less "around"?

---

EDIT: How to implement the answer below with regexp.union? I have a function that generates the regex:

```
def generateMergeRx(arr_with_keywords)
    arr_with_keywords.delete_if{|x| (x.include? " ") == false}
    matchRegexMerge = Regexp.new("(%{keywordReplace})" % {
        keywordReplace: Regexp.union(arr_with_keywords).source
    })
end
```

This is what it looks like using puts regexMerge.to_s:

```
(?-mix:(And\.\ z\ Kobyl\.|Ban\.\ W\.|B\.\ B\.|B\.\ G\.|Biel\.\ J\.)
```

It corresponds to that:

```
And. z Kobyl.
Ban. W.
B. B.
B. G.
Biel. J.
(...)
```

And then I call it like that:

```
regexMerge = generateMergeRx arr_with_keywords
some_string.gsub!(regexMerge.to_s.gsub!(/ /, "\s"), "\\1")
```

But what should I put instead of \1? Because at the moment input = output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
▶ str = 'zzzzzzzzz aaa
▷ bbbb ccccc yyyyyyyyy'
▶ re = "aaa bbbb ccccc"
▶ str.gsub /#{re.gsub(/ +/, '\s+')}/, re
#⇒ "zzzzzzzzz aaa bbbb ccccc yyyyyyyyy"
```

The general idea is to match any *spaces*, including `\n` and to replace them with original string.

Comment: Oh, yeah, this is exactly what I was looking for – and more obvious than I'd care to admit... Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I have a little bit of an issue implementing this idea. Would you mind taking a look? I updated the description above.

Comment: 1. Why do you call bang versions of `gsub!`? You ruined `regexMerge`, plus `gsub!` does not return the string if no replacements were made. 2. Also, please update a question with how `regexMerge` looks like.

Comment: 1. I often use them for simplicty. I have trouble replicating your example, as I get errors if I use #{} or if I don't convert the regex to str (as you can see, I have it as a regex type, not string type).
2. Done.

Comment: I don’t understand anymore what you are trying to achieve, but currently input = output just because your regexp doesn’t match anything. As soon, as you have working regexp, you might use block form of gsub: `str.gsub(/re/) { |m| m.gsub /\s+/, ' ' }`.

Comment: I do have a hard time explaining this. Basically, I want to replace all `\n`s but only if they occupy a place in the keyword sequences instead of spaces, not all `\n`s in general. So if one of my array elements is `Św. z Woc.`, I want to replace all `(Św.\nz Woc.)|(Św. z\nWoc.)` → Św. z Woc., but for multiple array elements at the same time.

Comment: Then turn back to your array and forget about regexps. Array should contain strings ⇒ `arr.each.reduce(str) { |memo, a| memo.gsub /#{a.gsub(/ +/, '\s+')}/, a }` must do the trick.

Comment: Thanks again for all the help. I have been attempting to to wrap my head around this all that time, but I am lacking in knowledge, as the `(str)` part is confusing me – I don't really know what to put there. According to the documentation, if I just omit that (str) part, it will start with the first element, which I guess is fine. But I still need to make a Regexp.union out of these to match any of these, but when I do, but the result is still the same.